# Matlab: What does it mean: input(row, col) = 255;

Tags: matlab

Can anyone explain what this line of code means?

```
input(row, col) = 255;
```

Comment: you are assigning the value 255 into the matrix `input` at position (row,col)

Comment: In an unsigned 8-bit image, setting a value to 255 basically means to set it to "pure white". Setting a value to 0 means setting it to "pure black". Here, you're setting the pixel in the image at location (row,col) to "pure white".

Comment: Thanks Amro for answer.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Image Processing:

to request a numeric input,

```
prompt = 'What is the original value? ';
result = input(prompt)
```

what you wrote is considering 'input' as a matrix and filling the element placed in 'row' and 'column' with value 255.